# Selecting from context in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am reading data from a Comma-separated Value (CSV) document and saving its contents to a database. Each row in the CSV file contains the following columns:

- Customer ID
- Latitude
- Longitude

Our domain model is as follows:

- `Customer` has many `Locations`
- `Location`

  - Latitude
  - Longitude

For each row, I am reading the `Customer ID` and look it up in the database:

```
var customer = (from c in Context.Customer
                where c.ID == id
                select c).SingleOrDefault();
```

If it does not exist, I create one:

```
if (customer == null)
{
    customer = new customers();
    customer.ID = id;
}
```

I do not save it at this point. Next, I create a new `Location`, and set its customer. Note that this customer may not actually be in the database yet.

Now consider the following: if a customer is not yet in the database, I create one. But I do not save it yet. Now the next row belongs to the same customer that I just created, it is not yet in the database. It will therefore create **another** customer.

When the time comes to save the graph to database, it will try to save two distinct customers with the same ID and fail.

How can I get Entity Framework to also select from what is in its context, even though it may not be persisted yet?

Comment: Is it full sample of your code? Are you attaching new `Customer` to the context after creating? Are you using Code First's DbContext or ObjectContext?

Comment: Oh my god, I am not! I am going to make the proper changes and let you know if it works out. Thanks for the swift response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have to attach newly created entities to the context instance.
Second, if you're using Code First, you can use [DbSet.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method - it can search for entities, which were not saved in store, but were already attached to context, without executing query to the store.

Comment: It appears the Find method only operates on primary keys. Is there a way to get it to operate on non-primary keys as well?

Comment: No, there isn't. I suppose the reason is that searching by PK is trivial for implementation (dictionary helps), which is not true for the rest of properties. 

Which case do you want to use it for? In your code sample you're searching customer by its PK.

Comment: I did not post a full code sample for brevity, but I have another case where I need to search by a name. In any case, I figured it out using the `Local` property on the `DbSet`, which seems to do the job well enough. Thanks anyway!